# How to calculate date of 5 weeks from today in php

Tags: php, date

In this function below i am calling a function using from_date and to_date in iteration. here for each iteration i am updating the from date value and when it comes to `$to_date` i am calculating the day from which it returns the date from now. for example the sharing_basis returns values like 2 weeks, 5 weeks....

for example:
I am using `$to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+".$sharing_basis));` to get the value of $to_date. the to_date returns date of the given number of weeks from now.

but here it is returning the same date everytime. i want to calculate `$to_date` based on `$from_date`

lets say,
for first iteration

```
$from_date = 2016-12-31
$to_date = $to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+5 weeks"));
```

I want to get the day date of 5 weeks from $from_date.

How can i do this?

```
function createSharingdates($productId){
    $startdate = getStartdate($productId);
    $sharing_basis = getSharingBasis($productId);
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE product_id='$productId' ORDER BY order_datetime";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
        $user_id = $row["user_id"];
        $from_date = $startdate;
        foreach ($user_id as $userid) {
            $to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+".$sharing_basis));
            addSharingDates($product_id,$userid,$fromdate,$to_date);
            $from_date = $to_date
        }   
    } else {            
        return false;       
    }
    $conn->close(); 
}
```

Comment: What is in `$sharing_basis` ?

Comment: Take some time and read the documentation at php.net for  **strtotime**

Comment: @Jan values like 2 weeks, 4 weeks, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$from_date = "2014-12-31";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days', strtotime($from_date)));
```

Comment: to add weeks you can use date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 weeks', strtotime($from_date)));

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way would be using the DateInterval class.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P5W'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Outputs:

```
2016-02-04
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$from_date = "2016-12-31";
$to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$from_date +5 weeks"));
```

this one works.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes are ideal for this.

```
$start=date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-12-31') );

$timezone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$interval=new DateInterval('P5W');

$date=new DateTime( $start, $timezone);
$future=$date->add( $interval );

echo $future->format('Y-m-d');
```